# switch between cells when segmentedControl has changed

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, swift

i have a custom UITableViewCell which contains an segmentedControl. This segmentedControl is suppose to control the second cell. When the index in segmentedControl has changed it should switch to another custom cell. How can i do something like this? i've tried implementing a IBAction in the viewController, but then i cant connect it to the segmentedControl in the xib file. If i put that method in the segmentedViewCell then i cant change the cells subclass. How can i obtain this?

Here is a little illustration. segmentedControl and the bottom view is in different cells.

[image]

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell! {

    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ImageViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as ImageViewCell


        cell.itemImage.image = itemFile


        cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, cell.bounds.size.width, 0, 0)
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None
        return cell

    } else if indexPath.row == 1 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("UtilityViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UtilityViewCell


        cell.titleLabel.text = itemTitle
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None
        cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, cell.bounds.size.width, 0, 0)

        return cell

    } else if indexPath.row == 2 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("DescViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as DescViewCell



        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None

        cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, cell.bounds.size.width, 0, 0)

        return cell

    }




    return nil
}
```

Comment: Hmm, cannot see the cells. Did you intend to post them?  I think I have some code near what you want to do but it would be great to understand more.  In my code I use the segmented controller to manage the display in a header and cell.

Comment: i've added the cellForRowAtIndex. The UtilityCell contain a property segmentedControl, which is suppose to the cell with indexpath.row = 2 between 3 different cells according to the segmentedControlIndex

Comment: Why would you like to have it inside UITableView? Is that only a part of bigger UITableView? Or would you like to show more than one pair of those two cells?

Comment: i've added a new image so u can see why.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a step by step. In your project's storyboard, create a `UITableViewController` scene. Add `UITableViewCell`s in it as indicated in the image below. Change your first cell's style to "custom" and add a `UISegmentedControl` with non-ambiguous auto layout constraints in it.

[image]

Before setting your code,

- Make sure that your `UITableViewController` scene has its class set
  to "TableViewController".
- Make sure to select Prototype Cells and Grouped TableView Style for your `UITableView` in Attributes Inspector.
- Make sure that your `UISegmentedControl` has a view tag set to 1 (see image).
- Make sure that the cell that contains the `UISegmentedControl` has
  its identifier set to "SegmentCell".
- Make sure that the second cell has its identifier set to "CellZero".
- Make sure that the third cell has its identifier set to "CellOne".
- Make sure that the fourth cell has its identifier set to "CellTwo".

Finally, your `UITableViewController` class file will contain the following code:

```
import UIKit

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var segment = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 2
    }

    func segmentAction(sender: UISegmentedControl) {
        switch sender.selectedSegmentIndex {
        case 0:
            segment = 0
        case 1:
            segment = 1
        case 2:
            segment = 2
        default:
            break
        }
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell: UITableViewCell!

        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("SegmentCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
            cell.selectionStyle = .None //if necessary

            let segmentControl = cell.viewWithTag(1) as UISegmentedControl
            segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex = segment
            segmentControl.addTarget(self, action: "segmentAction:", forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)
        } else {
            switch segment {
            case 0:
                cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CellZero", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
            case 1:
                cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CellOne", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
            case 2:
                cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CellTwo", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
            default:
                break
            }
        }

        return cell
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this might take an iteration until I better understand your need.

[image: Math Flash Card History View]

This from a demo project of some flash cards and I use a segmented control to decide to display all the historical games or just those of a certain type (addition, subtraction, etc.)  I had to deal with the issue of where to put the segmented control.  Inside the table or above the table.  The problem with inside the table is in my case the view reloads after each change.

But I do use he segmented control to change both the header and the cell contents.

So I can post the code for all this, or I can create a short demo code for the segmented control within a table cell (not sure how that will play out).

Comment: In your viewController it seems like the segmentedControl is outside the tableViewCell. My case is where the segmentedControl is inside the a cell and it need to change the content of another cell. If u could make a small demo or just a sample i would appreciate

Comment: Ok I get it.  I can make one later today USA time.

Comment: Just curious why you are using cells of this purpose.  You could draw two lines to simulate cells, drop in a segmented controller in the upper space and then based on changes update content on the second space.

Comment: i'm not sure i understand your idea, but i'm open for the idea if design wont be affected by it.

Comment: Well you place there objects in your storyboard file: 1) a UIIMageView, 2) A UILabel 3) A UISegmentedControl.  You let actions on the UISegmentedControl change the other two.

Comment: Well then i would not be able to scroll if content is bigger than the view, but i guess i could create a xib and then add it a scrollView in the viewcontroller?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62294/discussion-between-gamerchristian-and-minnesotasteve).

Answer (score 0):

override func numberOfSections(in intableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 2
}



func segmentAction(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
    switch sender.selectedSegmentIndex {
    case 0:
        segment = 0
    case 1:
        segment = 1
    case 2:
        segment = 2
    default:
        break
    }
    tableView.reloadData()
}
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell: UITableViewCell!

    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SegmentCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as UITableViewCell
       // cell.selectionStyle = .none //if necessary

        let segmentControl = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UISegmentedControl
        segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex = segment
        segmentControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(JobReportTableViewController.segmentAction(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
    } else {
        switch segment {
        case 0:
            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CellZero", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as UITableViewCell!
        case 1:
            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CellOne", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as UITableViewCell!
        case 2:
            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath as IndexPath)as UITableViewCell!
        default:
            break
        }
    }

    return cell
}
```

}